# Google Big Query 16 digits timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please help me convert 16 digits timestamp in Big Query to normal date_time format

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want [`timestamp_micros()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_micros):

```
select timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)
```

Comment: is not work
"TIMESTAMP value is out of allowed range: from 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00"

Comment: @Galat . . . Did you use `timestamp_millis()` or `timestamp_micros()`?  I had the wrong function initially.